# querySelectorAll is not returning updated nodelist inside a recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, dom, dom-manipulation, selectors-api

I am trying to grab an element in the DOM that is created in the future. To simplify, When the user uploads an image by clicking on an upload button, a div is created in the DOM, which has a class name of ".popup".

To check if the modal with class name ".popup" is created I am using a recursive function.
And it works fine when I use the querySelector method.

**The problem is, the user can upload multiple files, which will create multiple divs in the DOM with the same class name. When I use the querySelectorAll method to grab all the divs it always returns the first div, and does not grab the other ones. Looks like the let modals = document.querySelectorAll(".popup") does not update inside the recursive function.**

Any suggestions, what am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

```js
const attachRemoveBgEvent = () => {
  const input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      //Add Listner
      input[i].addEventListener("input", checkCropper);
  }
};

async function checkCropper(e) {
  async function checkModalIsCreated() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      function checkModal() {
        let modals = document.querySelectorAll(".popup");
        if (modals.length > 0 ) {
          createRemoveButton(modals);
          resolve();
        } else {
          setTimeout(checkModal, 1000);
        }
      }
      checkModal();
    });
  }

  await checkModalIsCreated();

}

const createRemoveButton = (modals) => {
console.log(modals);
}
```

I am expecting to get all the divs with the class name ".popup" if there is multiple of them get created in future. But I only get the first one, even if I am using querySelectorAll() method which should return a nodelist with all the divs that has that class name.

I also tried using getElementsByClassName() which returns a live HTMLcollection. But in the console, I do see the HTMLcollection contains all the items, but when I console.log the length, it's always one.

Comment: You should include a sample of the relevant HTML too.

Comment: Your function only recurses when there are no divs found. So as soon as the first one is created it will return rather than recursing.

Comment: I think you are taking the wrong approach. It sounds like you should look into a [DOM Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: Hi @Barmar,
Sorry for the confusion, I have updated the code. 
The checkCropper function is actually called whenever users upload an image. It is attached with the upload input field. 

The first time users upload an image, the first div with ".popup" class is created in the DOM. and the script works fine.

When the user upload a secord image, this time there is two divs with the class "popup". And the checkCropper function is also called again. So it should now return a notelist with two divs with the ".popup" class.

Comment: The problem is that it won't wait for the second upload to finish. It will return immediately because it finds the first popup.

Comment: Give `checkCropper()` a parameter that's the current number of `.popup`. Then it should wait for the length to increase.

Comment: You are correct, It returns once it finds the first popup div, and does not wait for the second one to be created. Can you please give me an example of the parameter? How can I make it wait till the second popup is created?

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, I have solved the issue. I need to track the number of popup already found.

Comment: You can post your code as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue, I just had to keep track of the popup I already found, and check if the length of the nodelist is larger.

```
// total number of popup found
let popupFound = 0;

const attachRemoveBgEvent = () => {
  const input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      //Add Listner
      input[i].addEventListener("input", checkCropper);
  }
};

async function checkCropper(e) {
  async function checkModalIsCreated() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      function checkModal() {
        let modals = document.querySelectorAll(".popup");
        if (modals.length > popupFound ) {
          popupFound = popupFound + 1;
          createRemoveButton(modals);
          resolve();
        } else {
          setTimeout(checkModal, 1000);
        }
      }
      checkModal();
    });
  }

  await checkModalIsCreated();

}

const createRemoveButton = (modals) => {
console.log(modals);
}
```